# MySQL REPLACE variable string

Tags: mysql, replace

I want to use MySQL query to change a link .

the link is like this :

http://website.com/click.php?ad_client=blablabla&add_id=548124&more=stuffhere

if I know the add_id number this is easy :

```
UPDATE table SET name = REPLACE(name, '&add_id=548124', '')
```

The problem is I have to change 5000 lines and I don't know the add_id number ... so what would be a correct mysql replace() code to remove **&add_id=*somenumber***  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE This....

```
 UPDATE table 
    SET name = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(name , 1, 
                    INSTR(name ,'&add_id') - 1),SUBSTRING(name , 
                    INSTR(name , '&more'), 
                    LENGTH(name ) - INSTR(name , '&add_id')))
```

Comment: this looks nice . I will try it now and post back .

Answer (score 0):

Either you can do it via [UDF - SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql) or you can simply write  PHP code which will replace value & update column again in table.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a stored procedure that uses a cursor to iterate over each row that needs updating.

In the procedure I would find the link to replace and then replace them, one by one.

I've made a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95afb/1) to show how you can get the part to replace inside an select.

I think this approach is clean and easy to read but it's possible to write this a update (that will most likely be hard to read).

Answer (score 0):

- first to see that it works :

  SELECT 'http://website.com/click.php?ad_client=blablabla&add_id=548124&more=stuffhere' INTO @link;
  SELECT 
  @link as full_link,
  SUBSTR(@link,LOCATE('&',@link),LOCATE('&',@link,LOCATE('&',@link)+1)-LOCATE('&',@link)) as remove_part,
  REPLACE(@link,SUBSTR(@link,LOCATE('&',@link),LOCATE('&',@link,LOCATE('&',@link)+1)-LOCATE('&',@link)),'') as final_link

And now for your UPDATE:

```
UPDATE table SET name = REPLACE(name,SUBSTR(name,LOCATE('&',name),LOCATE('&',name,LOCATE('&',name)+1)-LOCATE('&',name)),'')
```

Comment: np, it does the same thing as the first answer but using a different way, you can benchmark both to see which is the fastest for you

Answer (score 0):

try this with  `REPLACE`

```
 UPDATE Table1
 SET name = REPLACE(if(name like '%add_id=%','' , name ), 

 '&add_id=' , '' )
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8fcd/1)

Comment: not good ... i need to replace &add_id=423423 with '' .. and the number is random .

Comment: what result in my demo you want ?